# How to modyfy the part of the composite key on the database

Tags: database, entity-framework, key, procedure, put

There is a need to map different naming for the same real objects, depending on the client.

Table1:

- ID (primary key)
- NAME (unique)

Table2:

- MAIN_ID (foreign key to Table1.ID)
- CLIENT
- CLIENT_ID

The key on Table2 is a composite key of all of these 3 as this only gives uniqueness.

The relation is `1 to many`, so single object from Table1 can have many objects from Table2.

There is this PUT endpoint that allows to add new mappings providing the Table2.CLIENT_ID and Table1.NAME. Table2.Client is acquired from HTTP Context, so we can now who is calling the NAME by its CLIENTID. TableID (that equals MAIN_ID as well) is generated as Guid during addition.

But the PUT endpoint allows also to modify the entry that were recorded before. This allows to override CLIENT_ID which is partially the key on Table2.

PostgreSQL and EntityFramework is used. The latter does not allow to modify the key of existing row.

**Question 1: Is there more efficient design for this situation?**

My initial approach was to deal with this via a stored procedure which is going to override CLIENT_ID if the PUT request is coming for object already existing.

Then I have read about this remove-add approach, so removing this Table2 row and inserting the new one. I doubt it is proper one. Of course there are transactions, but my preference is single logical operation. It lower the risk that something goes wrong (deleted, but for some unexpected error not inserted => problem).

**Question 2: Assuming we need to stay with design above - what approach is best:**

- stored procedure
- delete-add approach
- ... any other?